# how to show TextView,Buttons On MapView (To Overlap On It)..?

Tags: android, layout, android-mapview

In my application i have mapview and I want to show distance in a textview and also a Button ,

I have done this.and tried this..
http://www.anddev.org/post3452.html#p3452

PROBLEM IS>>>>

I WANT TO SHOW TEXTVIEW AND BUTTON OVER THE MAP VIEW..
so I can See MAPVIEW in Full Screen..with other items over it(as we can see map through textview)..

Any SPECIFICATION NEEDED TO BE DONE IN xml FILE..??

Please..Reply me..
Thank You..in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can do that.

For eg:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:enabled="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="your api key" />

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Click"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:id="@+id/clickBtn" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks Rohit and Specially Mathew..for Replying..I got the solution..thanks..I will use this with transparent arrows for placemarks navigation too...

Answer (score 0):

create a layout with the RelativeLayout and embed the map view in it. Once set, set the relative position of your components as per your need.